# How can I fill in the missing data in the column with the value 0?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list `df_list` with 40 dataframes (elements), where `df_list[[1]]` is the first dataframe of the list and "Date" is a "POSIXt" object. The Frequency column takes into account the number of tweets at a certain date/time.

I would like to add the missing 'Data' and associate them with the value '0', this for each dataframe in the list.
How can I do this?

This is an example of dataframe in the list:

| Frequency | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 12:52 |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 12:53 |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 12:54 |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 12:56 |
| 4 | 2022-12-01 12:57 |
| 4 | 2022-12-01 13:00 |

What I expect:

| Frequency | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-12-01 12:51 |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 12:52 |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 12:53 |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 12:54 |
| 0 | 2022-12-01 12:55 |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 12:56 |
| 4 | 2022-12-01 12:57 |
| 0 | 2022-12-01 12:59 |
| 0 | 2022-12-01 12:58 |
| 4 | 2022-12-01 13:00 |

Comment: ```2022-12-01 12:51``` why do you count this time as missing? Is it based on the list of dataframe that you have? I can see why you add the other time steps as you want 1-min interval, but the first one doesn't make sense.

Comment: I gave more details in the question. I need these missing informations for creating time series object. For having every minute the number of tweets posted in a given period.

Comment: You added *"The Frequency column takes into account the number of tweets at a certain date/time."*. This does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to convert is to a `tsibble` (a time series tibble), and use the `fill_gaps()` function. You can specify that you want to fill it with 0 instead of the default `NA`, and choose a start time that's earlier than the first time observed in your data set if you wish (although agree with comments that it's not clear why that would be the case from the question).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)


dat <- tribble(
  ~freq, ~date,
  2,    "2022-12-01 12:52",
  3,    "2022-12-01 12:53",
  1,    "2022-12-01 12:54",
  2,    "2022-12-01 12:56",
  4,    "2022-12-01 12:57",
  4,    "2022-12-01 13:00"
)

dat |> 
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd_hm(date)) |> 
  as_tsibble(index = date) |> 
  fill_gaps(freq = 0, .start = lubridate::ymd_hm("2022-12-01 12:51"))
```

This returns something like:

```r
# A tsibble: 10 x 2 [1m] <UTC>
    freq date               
   <dbl> <dttm>             
 1     0 2022-12-01 12:51:00
 2     2 2022-12-01 12:52:00
 3     3 2022-12-01 12:53:00
 4     1 2022-12-01 12:54:00
 5     0 2022-12-01 12:55:00
```

You could then make this into a function, and use `map()` from purrr to apply it to multiple elements in a list.

Comment: I don't understand where I have to add the dataframe in tribble(...). I'm a beginner.

Comment: I've re-created the dataframe in your example code using `tribble` here, because you didn't share the data using `dput()`. I had to create a dataframe in order to make a demo. If you already have the data frame, you don't need make another one - just convert it to a `tsibble`.